# Loading generated maps into Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, world, pgm, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got some maps that I've generated using the gmapping/slam packages with a turtle bot.
However I would prefer to be working within the simulated environment provided by Gazebo.

Is there a way I can get the pgm/yaml files generated by ROS packages such as gmapping into Gazebo?
Ideally it would be loaded in as a heightmap, but even if I could just get the image in as a ground plane sort of thing that would be good.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199185/loading-generated-maps-into-gazebo/) by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a tool that can automate this (maybe the building editor for gazebo could help: http://wiki.gazebosim.org/wiki/Building_Editor). I previously used Blender to achieve what you describe. If you know how to use it, it's a few minutes of work to load the map image, trace the walls in 2D and then extrude walls from the 2D footprint, resulting in a mesh you can load in gazebo. How practical this is also depends on how often you have to do it and how complex the maps are, of course.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on 2014-12-10**:
Cheers, I think I'm going to have to do this unless I find an alternate method over the next couple of days. Since it is pretty much a one off in *this* case, it shouldn't be too bad.